# Running netcat listener and sql injection in one python script

Tags: python, subprocess, sql-injection

Hi so I'm pretty new to python programming and I've got an assignment that I'm busy with that requires me to do the following all in one python script:

1.Login to dvwa (BTW this is all being done in DVWA(Damn Vunerable Web Application)

2.Set up a listener

3.Send payload to DVWA using SQL Injection

4.Execute the payload (payload contains a simple netcat bind shell)

5.Receive the connection and use the shell

I've done most of this with success, the only thing I'm struggling with is creating a subprocess for the listener, I haven't worked with subprocesses before and it's very confusing.

So at the moment I'm calling netcat in a subprocess:

```
subprocess.call("nc -nvlp {}".format(port), shell=True)
```

But it's not executing the code after the listener subprocess because it's waiting for a connection, but a connection won't happen until the code below the listener gets executed. Any suggestions on how I would go about running more code after the listener subprocess? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, by running the subprocess in the background it completed the code below and gave me shell access.

So simply changing:

```
subprocess.call("nc -nvlp {}".format(port), shell=True)
```

To:

```
subprocess.Popen("nc -nvlp {}".format(port), shell=True)
```

Solved my problem !